# Remote Access of Raspberry pi using Xming and putty, Error

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, remote-access, putty, xming

I am trying to get started with raspberry pi, model B. As a way to avoid having to buy a monitor and hdmi cable and keyboard and mouse (no, I do not already have a tv, monitor, hdmi cable, usb keyboad and usb mouse), I am trying to use remote access through my laptop by connecting it to the router. I assigned fixed ip to raspberry pi by editing its cmdline.txt file. I can successfully ping it. (I am using raspbian). I can connect to it by using Xming and putty, well mostly. When I hit scratch, a program slowly loads, takes several seconds to fully draw the window. When I hit lxsession, I see a bunch of errors, but the raspbian desktop gets loaded but its empty. Why am I getting those errors? and Why is the desktop empty? 
Basically all I did was:

1. burned the raspbian OS to sd card.
2. Edited the cmdline.txt to append ip=xxx.xxx.xx (to match the same group as my computer's ip; I can ping my pie)
3. Connect Rp to my home router using ethernet cable.
4. install Xming and putty in my laptop and start them.
5. Enable X-11 forwarding in putty, and login to raspberry pi's ip address from 2.
6. try to load 'lxsession'

Is there anything I am missing?

I have attached here the screen shot of the error:

[image: Error]

PS: I accidentally posted this question into stackexchange instead. Sorry for double post.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know about the xming....but u can use vncserver to load the screen on your laptop...it is very easy to install on the pi and very easy to access the desktop of your pi via your laptop.....

it is detailed shown on the this following link...
https://kushrami.wordpress.com/2015/01/26/how-to-load-raspberry-pis-desktop-on-your-laptop-screen/